# How do I extend loader widget in Magento 2 so that a background image is shown everytime the loader appears

Tags: magento2

I have been trying to extend magento 2's `$.mage.loader` widget. I have have a requirejs-config.js file with the following lines

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'mage/loader' : 'Youssuph_Bakerscheckout/js/custom-mage-loader'
        }
    }
};
```

And the content of `custom-mage-loader.js` file is

```
  define([
    'jquery',
    'mage/template',
    'jquery/ui',
    'mage/translate'], 

function ($, mageTemplate) {

    'use strict';

    $.widget("bakers.loader", $.mage.loader, {

         options: {
                icon: '',
                texts: {
                    loaderText: $.mage.__('Please wait...'),
                    imgAlt: $.mage.__('Loading...')
                },
                template:
                    '<div class="loading-mask" data-role="loader">' +
                        '<div class="loader">' +
                            '<img alt="<%- data.texts.imgAlt %>" src="'+loadingBakersLogo+'">' +
                            '<p><%- data.texts.loaderText %></p>' +
                        '</div>' +
                    '</div>'
            }
    });
    return $.bakers.loader;
});
```

i have confirmed that this file loads in the browser but it just doesn't work. The loader works normally during page load and I see error message -

> Base is not a function

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Your **requirejs-config.js** it's right, but your js file no, change the params like this:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'jquery/ui',
    'mage/loader'],
function ($) {

    $.widget('your_namespace.loader', $.mage.loader, {
        options: {
            texts: {
                loaderText: $.mage.__('Foo')
            },
            template:
                '<div>Your template</div>'
        }
    });

    return $.your_namespace.loader;
});
```

Now use: **jQuery('body').loader('show')** and see your new custom loader!

Answer (score 2):

Its been a while but if anybody else stumbles upon this answer.

vjurado is not correct. The mistake lays in `requirejs-config.js`. Correct will be a reference withouth the "mage/", like this:

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'loader' : 'Youssuph_Bakerscheckout/js/custom-mage-loader'
        }
    }
};
```

The `custom-mage-loader.js` is correct as posted in the initial question.